# Open well submersible water pump starter

Tags: electrical, well-pump

I have an outdoor waterfall idea for decor, and I found that open well submersible water pump suit my needs best. My question is that: if the house is new construction and I can do whatever I want, can I ignore an electrical starter and don't use it? Can I just hard wire connect the pump directly to electricity and run it? Knowing that I can connect the pump directly to distribution board and change breaker current rating to any ampere that I want. Houses here in Oman Muscat are all using 220-240 volts alternating current 3 phase. I calculated flow rate and head and I found that I need 1 HP 3 phase pump.

Comment: it will trip you breaker or burn the wires

Answer (score 1):

A common electrical safety requirement which may or may not apply to your particular location in the world is to have a shutoff (either a switch or a circuit breaker) in sight of the location of the pump.

If your selected pump is one that requires a "starter box" you need that.

However, if you have 3-phase power available, 3-phase pumps that connect with no starter box are commonly available, as are "two-wire" single-phase pumps that require no "starter box." However, a single-phase 3-wire pump absolutely requires a starter box - so don't get one of those pumps if you don't want one. A 3-phase pump should be the most efficient type, which should matter to you since apparently you plan to leave it running all the time.

Note that a 2-wire pump typical has 3 wires and a single-phase 3-wire pump typically has 4, due to the convention of not counting the grounding wire.

In normal well applications the pump (2-wire, 3-wire, or 3-phase) is controlled by a pressure switch, which you may be confusing with a starter box - that, you won't need if your setup is purely continuous circulation.

Comment: Another common safety requirement may be GFCI/RCD protection for the circuit. Especially a circuit involving water.